# Why are my arrows on card carousel not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having troubles with my card carousel to work. I am still learning JS, but i'm positive that's the problem and i don't know how to fix it. Whenever i click on the button/arrow of this carousel, instead of sliding, it reloads the entire page. I checked everything, but obviously there's something that i keep missing. Here is the code in JS:

```
    (function($) {
    "use strict";

    $('.next').click(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel('next');return false; });
    $('.prev').click(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel('prev');return false; });
    
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<section class="container pt-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Vesti</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="postsCarousel">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 text-md-right lead">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary-outline prev" href=""><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary-outline next" href=""><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container pt-0 mt-2">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="card-deck">
                            <div class="card h-100">
                                <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img1.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body pt-2">
                                    <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Lorem</h6>
                                    <h2>
                                        <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card h-100">
                                <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img2.jpg" alt="Carousel 2">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body pt-2">
                                    <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Lorem</h6>
                                    <h2>
                                        <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card h-100">
                                <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img3.jpg" alt="Carousel 3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body pt-2">
                                    <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Lorem</h6>
                                    <h2>
                                        <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="card-deck">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img4.png" alt="Carousel 4">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body pt-2">
                                    <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Category 2</h6>
                                    <h2>
                                        <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img5.jpg" alt="Carousel 5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body pt-2">
                                    <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2"><span class="pull-xs-right">12.04</span> Category
                                        1</h6>
                                    <h2>
                                        <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img6.jpg" alt="Carousel 6">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body pt-2">
                                    <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Category 3</h6>
                                    <h2>
                                        <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. I think you forgot to add `bootstrap.min.js` in your code.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/xomswhnq/

```js
 (function($) {
    "use strict";

    $('.next').click(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel('next');return false; });
    $('.prev').click(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel('prev');return false; });
    
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section class="container pt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1>Vesti</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="postsCarousel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-md-right lead">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary-outline prev" href=""><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary-outline next" href=""><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container pt-0 mt-2">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="card-deck">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img1.jpg" alt="Carousel 1">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pt-2">
              <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Lorem</h6>
              <h2>
                <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img2.jpg" alt="Carousel 2">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pt-2">
              <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Lorem</h6>
              <h2>
                <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img3.jpg" alt="Carousel 3">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pt-2">
              <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Lorem</h6>
              <h2>
                <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="card-deck">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img4.png" alt="Carousel 4">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pt-2">
              <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Category 2</h6>
              <h2>
                <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img5.jpg" alt="Carousel 5">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pt-2">
              <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2"><span class="pull-xs-right">12.04</span> Category
                1</h6>
              <h2>
                <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="slike/img6.jpg" alt="Carousel 6">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pt-2">
              <h6 class="small text-wide p-b-2">Category 3</h6>
              <h2>
                <a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```